# Our flex resistors are giving incorrect values

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

We are working on a Arduino project where we use different methods to change the power of three LED's making our own "RGB" lamp and the current issue is with flex resistors. The idea is to use three flex resistors to control each lamp. We used the map function with out lowest & highest value making our lowest number 0 and our highest 255.
The issue is primarily that our number fluctuate a lot and the laps flicker like crazy.
Any recommendations?

We've tried changing our mapped numbers, both max and min. 
We've also played around with the code but with no success.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int bend1 = A0;
int bend2 = A4;
int bend3 = A5;
int green = 6;
int red = 10;
int blue = 9;
unsigned long previous = 0;
const long interval = 500;
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Started");
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previous >= interval)
  {
    previous = currentMillis;
    lcd.clear();
  }

  int value1 = analogRead(bend1);
  int value2 = analogRead(bend2);
  int value3 = analogRead(bend3);
  value1 = map(value1, 510, 910, 0, 255);
  value2 = map(value2, 490, 905, 0, 255);
  value3 = map(value3, 500, 900, 0, 255);

  if(value3 > 20)
  {
    analogWrite(blue, value3);
  }
  else
  {
    analogWrite(blue, 0);
  }
  if(value2 > 20)
  {
    analogWrite(red, value3);
  }
  else
  {
    analogWrite(red, 0);
  }
  if(value1 > 20)
  {
    analogWrite(green, value3);
  }
  else
  {
    analogWrite(green, 0);
  }


  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("GREEN");
  lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
  lcd.print("RED");
  lcd.setCursor(12, 0 );
  lcd.print("BLUE");

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(value1);
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print(value2);
  lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
  lcd.print(value3);

}
```

We should get the values 0,0,0 when all flex resistors are flat but instead they fluctuate from -10 ---> 90 in some cases. One of our fault might be faulty flex resistors. But we think there might be some code issues hidden also.

Comment: If you get -10 from the map then the min values in the code aren't really the lowest values... In any case, consider applying a time-filtering to the input. Something really simple like moving average would probably give you decent results to start with. Edit: On second thought, moving average with 500 ms interval will probably not work too well because it will be slow to update for deliberate input. Still, worth a try.

Comment: Why don't you print out the raw values before mapping them to see how they actually change?

Comment: Why are you always writing `value3`? Also `value3` is an awful name for a variable... You should really rewrite all this stuff from scratch w unit tests prior to using it on arduino.

Comment: How do you connect your flex resistors? Directly to your Arduino or with a pullup? A0 to A5 can add a pullup on the input. If you do not add one, you do not have a good signal.